# Where can I easily find best-paper-award-paper of a conference?

Tags: publications, phd, writing, electrical-engineering

Recently I read an article on tips for PhD students to improve their scientific writing skills. There, one suggestion was to find and read the best-paper-award-papers in highly reputed conferences in your discipline and understand the writing style, the way of presenting information, flow, language etc.. I believe it is worthwhile to spend some time on this to improve my writing skills. However, I tried whether there is an option to find such papers in a typical database after filtering information (my discipline is Electrical Engineering, so I tried [IEEE-Xplore](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/home.jsp)) but could not find it over there. So I would really appreciate if someone can suggest me the easiest way to find such papers online?

Note: I am interested in finding such papers related to highly reputed IEEE and [IFAC](https://www.ifac-control.org/) conferences.

Comment: Note that in some fields "Best paper awards" do not exist, so that tip may have a limited validity.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Thank you for your information. As far as I know, there are such awards in leading conferences in my research area: Electrical Engineering + Control systems.

Comment: Applies to computer science as well. Maybe there should be a tag for "conference papers are a thing" fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is a lot of variety in how much effort different conferences invest into making the information on best papers visible and long-term available.

- If you're lucky, the website of the conference lists previous best paper winners on their website. Sometimes this only applies to individual editions (years) of the conference.
- In a majority of cases, this might not apply. In these cases, you might be able to retrieve individual award winners by googling for search strings like  (if the conference name is ICSE), "ICSE Best Paper" and "ICSE Distinguished Paper". Such search strings may lead to tweets and researcher websites of award winners.
- Another option is to contact the steering committee of the conference and ask for the list of best papers. This might have the positive effect of raising awareness that there is interest in this information, which might at some point lead to more efforts into making the information available online.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the top conferences in your field and look to their websites to see whether best paper awards are present and, if so, which papers received such awards.